# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fechas'

Tags: python

```
len(listadias)
diasunicos=sorted(set(listadias))
len(diasunicos)

npordia= dict()

for x in diasunicos:
  npordia[x]=0

for x in diasunicos:
 for y in listadias: 
  if x ==y: 
    npordia[x]+=1
    
npordia 

nfechas = len(set(listadias))

plt.hist(listadias.nfechas)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-710b893c4123> in <module>()
      1 nfechas = len(set(listadias))
      2 
----> 3 plt.hist(listadias.nfechas)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'nfechas'
```

Answer (score 2):

In your very last line, instead of a `.` you need to put a `,`